# Find significantly different element

Tags: r, group-differences

I have following data and want to know is there really significant difference between those five objects: I have 5 objects and 3 different tests and their results like this. So this is very few rows and those tests are indipendent and different and if it is not possible to compare them as a group I would compare them each column at a time. So is there any method to find does they differ significantly and which of them (1,2,3,4,5) differs? How do you suggest to find that, maybe Kruskall-Wallis or something. I would do test in R.

```
1)17--18--25
2)18--15--23
3)14--13--19
4)22--13--18
5)17--26--37
```

Comment: Welcome, Anuket! It is a bit unclear precisely what you are asking. You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" link to the upper left of it to sharpen it up. Kruskal-Wallis seems like an inappropriate test for these data, since your are making repeated measurements in each object. Do you have reason to believe that these data are normally distributed? What kinds of assumptions are you making about the variance in each test?